# Do I need to include in documentation unhandled exceptions of nested methods?

Tags: java, exception, javadoc

For example, here is my code

```
 /**
     * Generates a message and saves it to a file where placeholders '%s' are replaced with values
     * provided during runtime from properties file.
     *
     * @param formattedMessage the formatted message where placeholders are replaced to '%s'
     * @param placeholderKeys  list with placeholder keys
     * @return string
     */
    public String generateMessage(String formattedMessage, List<String> placeholderKeys,
                                  String inputFilePath, String outputFilePath) {
        pathValidator.throwExceptionIfInputPathInvalid(inputFilePath);
        pathValidator.throwExceptionIfOutputPathInvalid(outputFilePath);
        List<String> placeholderValues = fileUtil.getPlaceholderValues(inputFilePath, placeholderKeys);
        String generatedMessage = String.format(formattedMessage, placeholderValues.toArray());
        fileUtil.writeToFile(outputFilePath, generatedMessage);
        return generatedMessage;
    }
```

As you can see, I have two method calls the only meaning of which is to throw exceptions.
Here is one of them:

```
/**
 * Throws exceptions if input file path is invalid
 *
 * @throws InvalidInputException         if input is blank
 * @throws InvalidFileExtensionException if provided file is not of a properties type
 * @throws PathNotValidException         if provided output file path is not valid
 * @throws FileNotFoundException         if provided input file is not found
 */
public void throwExceptionIfInputPathInvalid(String path) {
    throwExceptionIfOutputPathInvalid(path);
    if (!InputValidator.isExtensionValid(new File(path), ".properties"))
        throw new InvalidFileExtensionException("File should be of properties type");
    if (!Files.exists(Paths.get(path))) throw new FileNotFoundException();
}
```

Do I need to include these exceptions to docs of a `generateMessage` method?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd include these exceptions. Someone using the method `generateMessage` shouldn't have to know (or care) that internally it uses `throwExceptionIfInputPathInvalid`.

Alternatively, you could say something like "This method uses `throwExceptionIfInputPathInvalid` to check the validity of `inputFilePath` and `outputFilePath`. See its documentation for details on the exceptions it may throw."